# Is there a way to know which Program sent some files to the trash bin?

Tags: macos, mac, trash

I have seen some files appearing miraculously in the trash bin on my Mac, and I would like to know which program sent them there to be able to contact the Support and give some feedback.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that info isn't tracked by macOS, HFS+ or APFS.

Comment: Please provide some evidence to back up your assertion. Although what you say may be true, you need to back it up with some links from authoritative sources or explain how it works in a way that is comprehensive and indicative of your knowledge of the subject matter that is easily verified or refuted.

Comment: I've supported Macs professionally for 35 years and was both a certified Apple technician and Apple retail Genius, making me, IMO, an authoritative source. The filesystems' metadata doesn't have any way to track what process touched it last, nor does macOS. There's POSIX-level process accounting, but that doesn't track file movement.

Comment: A simple one-line answer can be made more fulfilling with the details you just added. An explanation in addition to the introductory negation is proper form. Thanks for the explication.